# Can I import a Library from a Library?

Tags: solidity, library, import

Is it possible to import a library into another library?
I give a simplified example below of what I'd like to achieve:

```
library structLib {
    struct Point {
        uint X;
        uint Y;
    }
}
```

```
import "./structLib.sol";

library ellipticCurveOperations {

    //adds point p1 to point p2
    function addition(Point p1, Point p2) internal returns (Point r) {

        //convert struct to array for use in precompiles
        uint[4] memory input;
        input[0] = p1.X;
        input[1] = p1.Y;
        input[2] = p2.X;
        input[3] = p2.Y;
        bool success;

        //use assembly to call Elliptic Curve precompile
        assembly {
            success := call(sub(gas, 2000), 6, 0, input, 0xc0, r, 0x60)
            switch success case 0 { invalid() }
        }
        require(success, "EC addition failed");
    }
```

```
import "./ellipticCurveOperations.sol" as Ops

contract addThings{
    using Ops for *;

    function add(Ops.Point a, Ops.Point b) public returns (Ops.Point){
        return Ops.addition(a, b);
    }
}
```

Would this work? Is there any syntax I need to change?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Quite an old question but yes, sure you can do that.

However, you specify the name of the library before the referenced struct.

So in your case, once `structLib` is imported, `ellipticCurveOperations` can access the `Point` struct from `structLib`.

```
structLib.Point
```